# What is this control?

Tags: .net, winforms

I tried ToolBar, ToolStrip, MenuStrip but they have not this look.

[image]

Should I create my custom renderer to achieve this?

These are my controls

[image]

Comment: This is a `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip` (Windows Form)

Comment: Is ToolStrip win32 control? I dont think utorrent is a .Net application.

Comment: @albert most, if not all `System.Windows.Forms` members are Win32 wrappers.

Comment: ToolStrip is built in NET from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTorrent is a closed-source program written in C++.  It uses controls that are only usable from a native program and has some of its own.  In general it is rather a slick program that was written by a highly skilled C++ programmer.  Reproducing its look-and-feel, and especially its very modest size, is very difficult to achieve.

This one is a Rebar control, the MSDN Library page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It doesn't have a .NET wrapper, creating your own is a rather massive project.  Assuming you don't also want to write a C++ program, you'll have to make do with a ToolStrip or the .NET 1.x ToolBar control.  The latter needs to be added to the toolbox on later VS versions, right-click it and click "Choose items".  You can get it similar enough but not exact.

Comment: It has the same colors of MainMenu. Is possible to get the gradients of MainMenu (for a windows version) in order to create a renderer for ToolStrip?

Comment: use ToolBar if you want the default theme colors.  ToolStrip's RenderMode = System is an approximation of that.